# grunt-contrib-connect: Only root is reachable, only on CI server

Tags: node.js, grunt-contrib-connect

I have been beating my head against a wall trying to figure out what is going on and I am hoping that someone can help.

I am using `grunt-contrib-connect` to start up a static server to run mocha specs against using selenium.  Locally on OS X 10.10, everything works perfectly.  Wonderful.

However, on the CI (Semaphore), the server starts, the specs start running, the first spec which hits `/` passes without problems.  However, the next specs that are connection to `/path/to/html/` all fail.  I threw some `curl` requests to see if maybe it was just a testing issue, I can `curl http://localhost:3023` works fine, `curl http://localhost:3023/path/to/html/` 404s.  The files are exactly where they should be and like I said, this all works on my local machine.

Any ideas what could be happening?  Here is my grunt config:

`connect: {
            options: {
                port: 4000,
                hostname: 'localhost',
                livereload: 35729
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    middleware: function(connect) {
                        return [
                            // Load the middleware provided by the livereload plugin
                            // that will take care of inserting the snippet
                            require('grunt-contrib-livereload/lib/utils').livereloadSnippet,
                            connect.bodyParser(),
                            connect.static(paths.dist.root)
                        ];
                    }
                }
            },
            test: {
                options: {
                    port: 3023,
                    host: '*',
                    base: paths.dist.root,
                    livereload: false,
                    debug: true,
                    directory: paths.dist.root,
                    middleware: function(connect) {
                        return [
                            connect.static(paths.dist.root)
                        ];
                    }
                }
            },
            dist: {
                options: {
                    port: 1338,
                    open: 'http://localhost:1338/',
                    base: paths.dist.root,
                    livereload: false,
                    keepalive: true
                }
            }
        },`

I am calling `connect:test` for the testing task.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was capitalization.... sigh.  The url path had capital letters in which OS X didn't care about, but Ubuntu did.  Once this was changed everything worked.